# Add class and onclick function to HTML string from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a query string to create HTML row

```
SELECT (
    SELECT 'Court 1' as th, 'Court 2' as th, 'Court 3' as th, 'Court 4' as th 
    FOR XML raw('tr'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
) AS headertr
```

and the output is

```
<tr><th>Court 1</th><th>Court 2</th><th>Court 3</th><th>Court 4</th></tr>
```

Is there any way to add an **onclick function** and **class** from SQL itself?

Comment: Sure, you can build any string you like in SQL... but why would you want to? And if you have a serious need, show your desired output.

Comment: No, SQL isn't JavaScript -- but you can put JavaScript on the same server that uses your SQL code. **OR** you can just modify the output string before sending a response to the user's browser, using whatever language is creating and sending that response (for which some of the usual suspects include Python, Java, PHP, and JavaScript). **EDIT:** I guess Dale K is right -- you may be able to construct any string you want, but that's not what SQL is intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear where you want the attributes to go, but you could do something like this

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT
      'myfunction()' AS [th/@onclick],
      'SomeClass' AS [th/@class],
      th
    from (VALUES
      ('Court 1'),
      ('Court 2'),
      ('Court 3'),
      ('Court 4')
    ) v(th)
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('tr'), TYPE
) AS headertr
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b9012fc7244ddf4a1046e53319ea871)